# Button Clearing Unprotected Cell is too slow/ not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that is clearing the content of the unprotected cells for different ranges on 4 different sheets. It is slow and is giving me a "Method of'Union' Clobal failed". Any suggestions? My code is attached below

```
Sub ClearAllUnLocked()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Range, rKlear As Range
Set rclear = Nothing
For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A").Range("F7:AA832")
    If r.Locked = False Then
        If rKlear Is Nothing Then
            Set rKlear = r
        Else
            Set rKlear = Union(rKlear, r)
        End If
    End If
Next r
rKlear.ClearContents

For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B").Range("D7:Y806")
    If r.Locked = False Then
        If rKlear Is Nothing Then
            Set rKlear = r
        Else
            Set rKlear = Union(rKlear, r)
        End If
    End If
Next r
rKlear.ClearContents

For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("E").Range("F7:AA855")
    If r.Locked = False Then
        If rKlear Is Nothing Then
            Set rKlear = r
        Else
            Set rKlear = Union(rKlear, r)
        End If
    End If
Next r
rKlear.ClearContents


For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Range("F7:AA3006")
    If r.Locked = False Then
        If rKlear Is Nothing Then
            Set rKlear = r
        Else
            Set rKlear = Union(rKlear, r)
        End If
    End If
Next r
rKlear.ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Try setting rKlear = Nothing before each sheet loop. and I believe rclear does not match rklear as the rest of the code.

Comment: One thing to do to start with is change `rclear` to `rKlear`.  (Put `Option Explicit` as the first line of every code module - it will help detect typos.)  I doubt whether that will fix your problem, but it may prevent future issues.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but your code suffers from too much repetition.  This would be easier to debug, and does the same thing:

```
Sub ClearAllUnLocked()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ClearUnlocked ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A").Range("F7:AA832")
    ClearUnlocked ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B").Range("D7:Y806")
    ClearUnlocked ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("E").Range("F7:AA855")
    ClearUnlocked ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X").Range("F7:AA3006")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ClearUnlocked(rng As Range)
    Dim rngClear As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Not c.Locked Then
            If rngClear Is Nothing Then
                Set rngClear = c
            Else
                Set rngClear = Union(rngClear, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    rngClear.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Those are large ranges though, so performance will not be great.

Comment: I usually just use `Next` without the variable name, so that I don't have to change the `Next` statement if I change the variable name in the `For` statement.  (But I do admit that it makes the code slightly more understandable if the variable name is explicitly stated at the start and end of the loop, especially if there are many loops being used.)

Comment: P.S. This code probably **will** fix the problem - I suspect it is the creation of the `Union` across multiple sheets which is the issue (refer original comment to question by TJYen), and your code automatically fixes that.

Comment: Yep I like to know where I am with nested loops, so always add the variable after `Next`.   I rarely change my variable names (except when editing code here on SO...)

Comment: Some people combine both, `Next 'c`, but we'd have to remember to change the commented variable name. But I also rarely change the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

[ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71178) has a neat (hacky) solution to this:

```
Sub EmptyUnlocked()
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F14") = ""
    On Error GoTo 0
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End Sub
```

It attempts to clear everything from range(s) but ignores errors for locked cells.

Personally, as you seem to have knowledge/control(?) over the ranges I would define range names for each sheet that includes *just* the unlocked cells. For each sheet use Ctrl-drag to select all the relevant areas; click into the Name box (top left) and give a name (without spaces). Then,

```
Range("the_name").ClearContents
```

(for each sheet).

Comment: Nice!  Note though - I started testing using ClearContents and that *didn't* work for me (Excel 2013)

Comment: @TimWilliams We must be thinking alike - I did exactly the same as you. :D

Comment: Strange. (I don't have 2013.) Does each named range only include unlocked cells? And is the corresponding sheet referenced each time?

Comment: @AndyG - my bad, I missed the piece about only including unlocked cells in the named ranges - Yes that would be fine.  In my testing i was using a "mixed" range and found it wasn't possible to use `ClearContents` in place of setting the `Value`.

Comment: Thanks. In my ranges there are unprotected and protected cells. So for the code above would I need to only have the cells that are unprotected in the range.?

Comment: Yes. But you would only have to select them once. Thereafter the range name will refer to the unprotected cells. The range name remains useful for formatting the cells, and for selecting them. (You can select them via the Name Box dropdown.)